# XMLWorkerHelper ordered list style

Tags: itext

I need to style ordered list elements in pdf generated from HTML. I know this is not supported http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm in way I tried:

```
ol li:before {
    content: counter(cnt-1) ". ";
    counter-increment: cnt-1
}

ol > li > ol > li > ol li:before {
    content: counter(cnt-1) "." counter(cnt-2) "." counter(cnt-3);
    counter-increment: cnt-3
}
```

Is there any solution to add processing ol attributes (content, counter, counter-increment) to itextsharp?

Comment: Before you get to `content` and `counter`, you'll actually need to tackle `:before` which isn't supported. I think the sort answer is no, there is no built-in solution to this. You'd have to write your own logic, probably a `CssApplier` of some sort. You'll also probably need to find a way to persist state information so that counters can increment across tags. I think all of the currently implemented CSS attributes are stateless, `bold` is `bold` always, but `counter` is 2 if it was previously 1. I would crack the source and watch what iTextSharp is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I processed nested ul elements with HtmlAgility + CSS before converting to PDF

```
ol { list-style-type:none; list-style:none;}



public string CustomOrderedListNumbering(StringBuilder sb, string xpathRoot)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument() { OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true };
            HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("meta");
            HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("link");
            doc.LoadHtml(sb.ToString());
            HtmlNodeCollection mainOls = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpathRoot);

            if (mainOls != null)
            {

                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in mainOls)
                {
                    Recursive(node, "", 1, 1);
                }
            }
            string htmlMainPart = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

            htmlMainPart = htmlMainPart.Replace("<br>", "<br />");
            return htmlMainPart;
        }

        private void Recursive(HtmlNode nodeOl, string baseNum, int depth, int counter)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection lis = nodeOl.ChildNodes;

            foreach (var li in lis)
            {
                string num = baseNum + counter + ".";

                var textNode = li.SelectSingleNode("./text()") as HtmlTextNode;
                if (textNode == null)
                {
                    textNode = li.SelectSingleNode("./*/text()") as HtmlTextNode;
                }
                textNode.Text = num + " " + textNode.Text;

                var childOls = li.SelectNodes("ol[@class='number']");

                if (childOls != null)
                {
                    foreach (var cOl in childOls)
                    {
                        Recursive(cOl, num, depth + 1, 1);
                    }
                }

                counter++;
            }
        }
```